# Accepting T or Array<T> not working even with Union type

Tags: typescript

I have a **TypedMapper** utility class that takes either:

- a hash/dictionary input of type `T`
- an array of hash/dictionaries of type `T[]`

From a flow standpoint it looks like this:

[image: flow diagram]

And to enable these dual structures as input/output I have the following as a map() function:

```
public map() {

  return Array.isArray(this._inputData)
    ? this._inputData.map((item: T) => this.convert(item)) as T[]
    : this.convert(this._inputData) as T;
}
```

The TypedMapper class works fine but when I use it I want it the map() function to return a discrete type `T` or `T[]` not the union of these two types. For example, in the following unit test we get successful JS results *but* the type is not known to be `T` or `T[]`:

```
const config = {
  passThroughs: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
  defaults: {
    foo: 12345
  }
};
const data = {
  bar: 'hello world'
};
interface IFooBarBaz {
  foo: number;
  bar: string; 
  baz: string;
}
const mapped = new TypedMapper<IFooBarBaz>(data, config).map();
expect(mapped.foo).to.equal(12345);
expect(mapped.bar).to.equal('hello world');
expect(Object.keys(mapped)).to.include('baz');
expect(mapped.baz).to.equal(undefined);
```

as the following screenshot illustrates:

[image: ts error]

Can anyone help me to understand how to ensure that -- based on the input structure being an Array or not -- that the output data structure is known discretely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting issue.  It would be great if TypeScript performed [type inference on optional generic types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400); then I think we'd be able to expand `TypedMapper<T>` to `TypedMapper<T,D extends T | T[]>` and allow `D` to be inferred from the constructor.  Then the output of `map()` would be `D` and you'd be all done.

But it doesn't.

What you *can* do is something like this: create two subclasses (or sub interfaces) of `TypedMapper<T>` like so:

```
interface ArrayTypedMapper<T> extends TypedMapper<T> {
  map(): T[]
}
interface NonArrayTypedMapper<T> extends TypedMapper<T> {
  map(): T
}
```

and create a static method that you use instead of the constructor:

```
class TypedMapper<T> {
...
  static make<T>(inputData: Partial<T>[], config: any) : ArrayTypedMapper<T>
  static make<T>(inputData: Partial<T>, config: any): NonArrayTypedMapper<T>
  static make<T>(inputData: Partial<T>[] | Partial<T>, config: any): TypedMapper<T> {
    return new TypedMapper<T>(inputData, config); 
  }
```

Now the overloaded `make` function will recognize if the `inputData` is an array or not and return a narrowed `TypeMapper<T>` type:

```
const mapped = TypedMapper.make<IFooBarBaz>(data, config).map();
// mapped: IFooBarBaz
const mappedArr = TypedMapper.make<IFooBarBaz>([data], config).map();
// mappedArr: IFooBarBaz[]
```

This is about as close as I can get.  There may be other ways to do it, but all of the ways I could actually get working involve specialized subclasses of `TypedMapper<T>`.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, type inference does not cross function boundaries.

You could express what you want with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), but for that `map()` must have `data` as parameter, and then you can declare two overloads for `map`, one taking object and returning object, another one taking array and returning array.

It's hard to give precise answer because you don't give definition for `TypedMapper` in your question, but something like this could work:

```
class TypedMapper<T, D> {
    constructor(public config: { passThroughs: string[], defaults: Partial<T> }) {
    }
    public map(d: D): T;
    public map(d: D[]): T[];
    public map(d: D | D[]): T| T[] {
         return Array.isArray(d)
                ? d.map((item: D) => this.convert(item)) as T[]
                : this.convert(d);
    }
    public convert(data: D): T {
        return undefined;
    }
}

const config = {
  passThroughs: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
  defaults: { foo: 12345 }
};
const data = {
  bar: 'hello world'
};

interface IFooBarBaz {
  foo: number;
  bar: string; 
  baz: string;
}

const mapped = new TypedMapper<IFooBarBaz, typeof data>(config).map(data);
mapped.foo === 12345;
mapped.bar === 'hello world';

const a = [data, data];

const mappedArray = new TypedMapper<IFooBarBaz, typeof data>(config).map(a);
mappedArray[0].foo === 12345;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some (probably unsatisfactory) choices:

The first choice is to explicitly cast that mapped value:

```
expect((<IFooBarBaz>mapped).bar).to.equal('hello world');
```

A more interesting choice is to wrap it in a type guard.

```
   if(!Array.isArray(mapped)) {
        expect(mapped.bar).to.equal('hello world');  // No explicit casting!
        expect(mapped.baz).to.equal(undefined);
   } else {
        // Fail the test here!
   }
```

In this case, the typescript compiler is clever enough to apply logic: since the code within the `if` block is only run if `mapped` is not an array, `mapped`  has to be of type `IFooBarBaz`

---

I don't know if this counts as 'the output structure is known discretely'.

Comment: The explicit typecast kind of defeats the purpose of the Generic type and I see how the external type guard you suggest would work but it comes at an unnecessary runtime conditional which I'd prefer to avoid. Is there no way for the existing _internal_ type guard to be understood implicitly?